# If Statement Against Dynamic Variable

Tags: powershell, if-statement, variables, foreach, indirection

I am attempting to do something similar to the following ...

```
New-Variable -Name "state_$name" -Value "True"
if ("state_$name" -eq "True") {
    Write-Host "Pass"
} else {
    Write-Host "Fail"
}
```

I have attempted this a number of different ways but it is not working exactly how I would like it to work. I need to write the if statement to account for a dynamic variable as these values will change inside of a `foreach` loop.

I have provided a simple example above for proof of concept.

Comment: Did you try to use `Hashtable`?

Comment: there is _reason_ why variable-named variables are STRONGLY disrecommended. [*grin*] it's quite difficult to get the name correctly after you create that $Var. ///// what is the _goal_ of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
if ("state_$name" -eq "True") {
```

with:

```
if ((Get-Variable -ValueOnly "state_$name") -eq "True") {
```

That is, if your variable name is only known *indirectly*, via an expandable string, you cannot reference it directly (as you normally would with the `$` sigil) - you need to **obtain its value via `Get-Variable`**, as shown above.

However, as [JohnLBevan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361842/johnlbevan) points out, you can **store the variable *object* in another (non-dynamic) variable, so that you can then get and set the dynamic variable's value via the `.Value` property**.
Adding `-PassThru` to the `New-Variable` call directly returns the variable object, without the need for a subsequent `Get-Variable` call:

```
$dynamicVarObject = New-Variable -Name "state_$name" -Value "True" -PassThru
if ($dynamicVarObject.Value -eq "True") {
    "Pass"
} else {
    "Fail"
}
```

---

That said, there are usually better alternatives to creating variables this way, such as using *hashtables*:

```
$hash = @{}
$hash.$name = 'True'

if ($hash.$name -eq 'True') { 'Pass' } else { 'Fail' }
```